# aadsync from cloud to onpremise

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have setup an Azure AD connect server in my lab network and through it I have 4 users fully syncing between local domain and O365. The 4 users were created originally in the local domain and automatically synced to O365. When I recently added a new licensed user in O365 I found that it does not sync back to my local domain, even when I do a full sync as shown below:

> Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial

Is it possible to cause a user that was initially created in O365 to sync to the local domain or do I have to first create the user in my local domain?

Comment: it is better to use Azure AD Connect since Dirsync and azure AD sync are now deprecated.

Comment: I am using Azure AD Connect.